# Problem installing Ubuntu on laptop. Fans go to max rpm and laptop shuts down after about 30 seconds

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, shutdown

Windows refugee here. I am trying to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB drive, but I'm sadly not getting very far. When I try Ubuntu without installing everything seems to be working just fine during the first 30 seconds, but after that the fans of my laptop kick in on full blast and shortly after that the system just shuts down.

My first guess was that there was some background activity that put too much load on the CPU, but all the cores are nearly idle (I have enough time to check before it shuts down). It also doesn't feel warm to touch. 
My second guess is that there is something wrong with the sensors, and that the computer thinks that it is overheating and shuts down because of that.

I also tried skipping the 'try without installing' and going straight to the installation, but the same thing happens there. 
Windows boots and works just fine.

Hardware: 
Intel core i7 6700K
Nvidia gtx 960m 
16gb ddr3 RAM
250gb SSD and 1tb HDD

Comment: Could you please add some info about your hardware ?

Comment: Added hardware information

Comment: What laptop manufacturer / model is it ?

Comment: Its a clevo barebone laptop assembled by a small local company

Answer (score 0):

What version of ubuntu?

32 or 64 bit - I assume 64 bit

What BIOS does the motherboard have & since this sounds like off brand... is the BIOS  the latest ?

What motherboard does it have?

Its pretty rare that the liveCD system would act like this ?